# phantomjs works on one machine, but can't find jquery on another?

Tags: jquery, phantomjs

phantomjs works on one machine, but on another machine when running the exact same command it return an error

```
Can't find variable: $
```

The phantomjs folder containing binary, scripts and other files are copy of the same source on both machine.

Both machines are centos.

The command I am running is command to print webpage as pdf. and it works fine on first machine.

the command

```
/opt/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs script.js url
```

script.js

```
...
page.open(req.url, 'get',  function (status) {
...
page.evaluate(function() {

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('no-print');
while(elements.length > 0){
    elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
  }
});

page.render(output, {format:'pdf'});
...
phantom.exit();


});
```

what settings I am missing ?

**Update**

- After manually including jquery, I am not getting a error, but very slow performance and one empty page in result.
- I tried both machine without using jquery in the script, the first worked the second did not.

Comment: Looks like the jquery file may be missing

Comment: Where is that suppose to be on centos ? both machines are centos.

Comment: Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors. Maybe the jQuery is simply not loaded, because of a network misconfiguration. Do you have the same PhantomJS version on both machines? Which is it?

Comment: Same phantomjs 1.9.8  it is a copy of the same folder for both machines. I will log errors and update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for my problem was to add

```
127.0.0.1 hostname.com
```

to

```
/etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 2):

Try explicitly including jquery from a hosted site: `page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js', function(){<your logic>});`. Jquery is only available if the webpage you are visiting has it included or you add it.

Comment: That help, but did not solve the problem. First I am not sure why the second machine is not loading jquery as the first one. second even after include jquery as you mentioned(downloaded to local file), phantomjs returned white page after long wait, instead of several pages with content in few seconds on the first machine.  what configuration could be wrong ?

Comment: If including jquery has caused the first machine to stop working it could mean the website your hitting uses a different version of jquery and when you include v1.8 you override the global "$" variable. Do you have a code snippet for what you are attempting or are you just using the command line?

Comment: I tried both machines without jquery, the first worked the second did  not.

Comment: Since you are not using jquery in your evaluated code the error must be emanating from the site's js code not yours. Does the error actually block the pdf from being generated, or does it cause the pdf to be blank?